# Ajax form only works the first time

Tags: forms, ajax

I have this simple ajax form with some ajax taxonomy checkboxes and a function that renders the content when the users changes the selected checkboxes. Everything work fine, the first time. The second time the user changes a checkbox I get this error:

`Undefined index: form_build_id in ajax_get_form() (line 320 of /var/www/mf/includes/ajax.inc)` and `Invalid form POST data.`

The only strange thing I've seen is when I inspect the request, there are a settings command, and ok insert command and another empty insert:

```
{command:insert, method:prepend, selector:null, data:, settings:null}
```

And in my html there is an empty .

My form:

```
function courses_lists_form($form, &$form_state) {dd(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(1); // 1 = courses taxonomies vid
  $terms_array = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $terms_array[$term->tid] = $term->name;
  }
  $form['taxonomias'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $terms_array,
    '#title' => t('TEMÁTICAS'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'courses_lists_form_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'courses-lists-ajax',
    ),
  );
  $form['block'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="courses-lists-ajax">',
    '#markup' => mf_form_commons_courses_lists_gen(0, 0, TRUE, 'matrix', array(0 => 9), ''),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}

function courses_lists_form_ajax($form, &$form_state){
  $taxs = array();
  foreach ($form_state['values']['taxonomias'] as $tid) {
    if($tid) $taxs[] = $tid;
  };
  $outp = '<div id="courses-lists-ajax">';
  $outp .= mf_form_commons_courses_lists_gen(0, 0, TRUE, 'matrix', $taxs, '');
  $outp .= '</div>';
  return $outp;
}
```

Comment: try putting $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; in courses_lists_form_ajax() function.

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried this solution; http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31298/11310, and had no luck, still get the errors on the second call. Thanks

Comment: There was an error in the generated markup. A missing closing div was messing everything. Now everything work as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the generated markup. A missing closing div was messing everything. Now everything work as expected. Thanks.